# print average percentage of a student from an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, iteration

The program is supposed to calculate and print out a given student's average percentage.

Unfortunately I am only able to print out the average percentage of the last student name in the array. 
I want to know where exacltly I am going wrong with my coding.
Thanks. Heres my code below.

```
def averagepercentage():

    scores = int(name_marks[1]),int(name_marks[2]),int(name_marks[3])
    ap = sum(scores)/3

    return ap

N = int(input('Number of students: ')) # total number of students
marks = int()
arr = []

for i in range(N):
    name_marks = input('name & marks').split() #enter name & three different scores 
    name = str(name_marks[0])
    arr.append(name)
    print(arr)

student_name = str(input('student_name'))
for x in arr:
    if student_name in x:

        print (x)

        print("%.2f" %averagepercentage())
```

Comment: You need to replace 'name = str(name_marks[0])' with 'name = averagepercentage(name_marks)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first loop:

```
for i in range(N):
    name_marks = input('name & marks').split() #enter name & three different scores 
    name = str(name_marks[0])
    arr.append(name)
    print(arr)
```

you don't store the marks of the previous students, you replace your variable `name_marks` by the last marks from your input

the `if student_name in x:` looks if `student_name` is included in `x`, which is not exactly what you want to do, consider doing `if student_name == x:` instead.

Then:

```
def averagepercentage():

    scores = int(name_marks[1]),int(name_marks[2]),int(name_marks[3])
    ap = sum(scores)/3

    return ap
```

looks at the global variable `name_marks` to compute the average, but this variables only contains the value of the last student (because of my first remark)

what you can do, to keep most of your code structure is:

```
for i in range(N):
    name_marks = input('name & marks').split() #enter name & three different scores 
    name = str(name_marks[0])
    arr.append((name,averagepercentage()))
    print(arr)

student_name = str(input('student_name'))

for x in arr:
    if student_name in x:
        print ("student :" + x[0])
        print("average :" + x[1])
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks!!! all this time I didn't realised i put my function averagepercentage() in a wrong place. your answer is very informative. Thank you!!!